# Is "being harmonic conjugate" a symmetric relation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

The question is:

Prove or disprove the following: If $u,v:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$
are functions and $v$ is a harmonic
conjugate of $u$, then $u$ is a harmonic conjugate of $v$ (in other words, show whether or
not the relation of being a harmonic conjugate is symmetric)

I'm pretty sure i'm correct in saying it isn't a symmetric relationship... But I'm wondering if someone can think of a direct counter-example to prove me right. Or is there an algebraic way to prove this that's better?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $\LaTeX$ tip: For $\mathbb R^2 -> \mathbb R$, you can write \to and get $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Ian , Does holomorphic simply mean differentiable at every point within the domain of the function? Or is there more to it than thaat... and are analytic and holomorphic synonymous?

Comment: @RobertCardona Wow! I've wasted so much time writing `\rightarrow`...

Comment: Just about any example would work!

Comment: @AndresCaicedo in the example in the answers below, I'm not understanding what u and v are in the Cauchy equations? how do you differentiate $f(z)$ with respeect to x!?

Comment: or have I simply forgotten that $z=x+iy$?

Comment: The notation I've seen uses $z=x+iy$ and $f(z)=u(x)+iv(y)$.

Comment: @Douglas Holomorphic means "differentiable in the sense of complex numbers". This is tremendously stronger than differentiability as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is used synonymously with "analytic" in certain contexts, but this is somewhat abuse of notation. The word "holomorphic" is all about the existence of the derivative, while the word "analytic" is all about the convergence of the power series to the function. These turn out to be equivalent, but this is a nontrivial fact, so *defining* the two to be synonymous is rather misleading.

Answer (score 5):

In general:
$$f=u+iv\implies if = -v +iu,$$
i.e., $v$ is a harmonic conjugate of $u$ $\implies$ $u$ is a harmonic conjugate of $-v$.

Comment: Much nicer than my answer!

Comment: @Ian, thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest example I can think of. $f(z)=z$ is clearly holomorphic, but $g(z)=Im(z)+iRe(z)$ is not, because when you look at the second Cauchy-Riemann equation you get $1 \neq -1$.